# Want to Update the Shopify cart when someone update the quantity

Tags: shopify, cart, shopify-template

I want that whenever customer update the quantity in cart the Shopify page automatically update that quantity. As, I don't want to add the update cart button and have no idea how can I do this.Can Someone Help in this Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax requests to implement this on the cart page. Shopify has a comprehensive Ajax API for that. See links below:

- [Getting started with the Ajax API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/getting-started)
- [Cart API reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart)

  - [update](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#post-cart-update-js) - useful on updating cart notes, attributes or multiple quantities at once
  - [change](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#post-cart-change-js) - set quantity for the exiting item in the cart